# How to add/remove li tag dynamically based on variable

Tags: jquery

How to dynamically add and remove based on a condition? I tried the below code but it is not working. I am trying to do it on page load. I will send true or false from template using hidden input. And if true add a tab, else remove the tab in script using jquery. Can any one please let me know.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="tab-heading">Person</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" class="tab-heading">Provider</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" class="tab-heading">Researcher</a></li>
    <li style='float: right;'>
        <button type="button" id="saveall" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</button>
    </li>

</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="override" id="override" value="true">


var override= $('#override').val();

if(override){
    $('ul.nav').append(" <li><a data-toggle='tab' href='#menu2' class='tab-heading' id='overridecanges'>Researcher</a></li>");
}else{
    $('#overridecanges').remove();
}
```

Comment: Please specify when you want to add or remove li like on button click, on link click etc.

Comment: @JaydipShingala I want to do it on page load. I will send true or false from template. And if true add a tab, else remove the tab in script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `$(this)` and compare with string.

```js
var override = $('#override').val();
if (override =="true") {
  $('ul.nav').append("<li id='#overridecanges'><h1>Cancer information</h1></li>");
} else {
  $('ul.nav').find('#overridecanges').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="tab-heading">Person</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" class="tab-heading">Provider</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" class="tab-heading">Researcher</a></li>
  <li style='float: right;'>
    <button type="button" id="saveall" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</button>
  </li>

</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="override" id="override" value="true">
```

False condition

```js
var override = $('#override').val();
if (override=="true") {
  $('ul.nav').append("<li id='#overridecanges'><h1>Cancer information</h1></li>");
} else {
  $('ul.nav').find('#overridecanges').remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="tab-heading">Person</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" class="tab-heading">Provider</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" class="tab-heading">Researcher</a></li>
  <li style='float: right;'>
    <button type="button" id="saveall" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</button>
  </li>

</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="override" id="override" value="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than inserting / removing it - have it there all the time and simply hide / show it based on your condition. In the following - I m dispensing with the hidden input alltogether and simply toggling it on the button click.

Obviously there is a lack of styling and I had to make the li's and h1 display inline, but this is a better approach than trying to manipulate the DOM each time the condition changes. To be honest - if I was doing this - I would add / remove a class to the li to show / hide it - but .toggle() does exactly this in jquery-land.

```js
$('#toggleButton').click(function(){
    $('#overridecanges').toggle();
})
```

```css
#overridecanges {display:none}
li, h1 {display: inline}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="tab-heading">Person</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" class="tab-heading">Provider</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" class="tab-heading">Researcher</a></li>
    <li id='overridecanges'><h1>Cancer information</h1></li>
    <li style='float: right;'>
        <button type="button" id="saveall" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</button>
    </li>

</ul>

<button type="button" id="toggleButton">Click Me to Toggle It</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you case `$(this).find('ul.nav')` will not point to any li inside ul.

Your requirements is not enough clear to me,

But any way let suppose when page is loaded i want to execute the following code:

**NOTE :- if(override) will always true because override will always a string value i.e 'true' or 'false',**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var override= $('#override').val();

    if(override=='true'){

        $('ul.nav.nav-tabs').closest('ul.nav').append("<li id='overridecanges'><h1>Cancer information</h1></li>"); 
    }else{
        $('#overridecanges').remove();
    }

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var override= $('#override').val();
   
    if(override=='true'){
    
        $('ul.nav.nav-tabs').closest('ul.nav').append("<li id='overridecanges'><h1>Cancer information</h1></li>"); 
    }else{
        $('#overridecanges').remove();
    }
    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" class="tab-heading">Person</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" class="tab-heading">Provider</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" class="tab-heading">Researcher</a></li>
  
    
    <li style='float: right;'>
        <button type="button" id="saveall" class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</button>
    </li>

</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="override" id="override" value="false">
    

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @An User try this answer